# Difference between LR parsing and Shift-Reduce parsing?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammars, parsers, natural-language-processing

I'm learning natural language processing and I can't understand the difference between [Shift-Reduce parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-reduce_parser) and [LR parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser).

As I've understood from Wikipedia, shift-reduce is just a name of a class of parsing algorithms which includes LR, LALR, SLR and other. But some [articles](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cse304/Fall08/Lectures/lrparser-handout.pdf) describe algorithm of shift-reduce parsing like it is a separate algorithm. So what is the difference between algorithm of shift-reduce parsing and algorithm of LR parsing?

Comment: 1/ Never assume a definition is universally accepted, people tend to adapt them for their purpose. 2/ I don't see how you deduce from that set of slides -- which by nature are terse and a support for a presentation which often give information needed to understand them -- that the authors are not considering shift reduce as a class of algorithm of which LR is a member (slide 22 for instance seem to characterize LR as a table-driven shift reduce algorithm).

Comment: @AProgrammer So the difference lies in the fact that LR is table-driven, and shift-reduce uses logic statements?

Comment: For me, shift-reduce is a class of algorithms, LR is a member of that class, the fact that it happens to use a table is not a very important characteristic (table are just a convenient way in general to describe a function and for LR how it is determined).  Asking the difference between shift-reduce and LR is like asking the difference between a car and a Ferrari, and stating that the difference is that LR is table-driven while shift-reduce is uses logic statements is like stating that the Ferrari is red while a car is colored.

Comment: @AProgrammer Thank you for clear explanation!

Comment: @AProgrammer How about answering the question?